# How to show the name of all owners whose name starts with a specific letter with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

How would you use the command line to show the name of all the owners (which is the table) that starts with a specific letter?

Comment: ? Do you want to query a database table called owners  from the command line? What have you tried what isn't working?  You should be a able to pass the query in? Or do you need help to write the query ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [LIKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) pattern match operator in your query. For example, to match owners starting with "A":

```
SELECT o.name 
FROM owners o 
WHERE o.name LIKE 'A%'
```

Run the query with `psql -c "query here"`

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b19c/2)